# NullPointer while loading jrxml file with DynamicReport object

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am trying to load a *JasperReports* jrxml template to my *DynamicReport* object but I am getting a null pointer without knowing from where it comes.

The code practically is like this:

```
DynamicReport dr = new DynamicReport();
DynamicReportBuilder drb = new DynamicReportBuilder();
......
drb.setTemplateFile("styles/myreport.jrxml");
dr = drb.build();
```

Then I call

```
 JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), resultSetDataSource);
```

The error is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperDesign(DynamicJasperHelper.java:200)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:535)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:518)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:283)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:236)
```

Does anyone has any idea?

ps: I am using *iReport 5* (tried even with 4) with *DynamicJasper 3.1.8*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamicJasper And JasperReport needs to be compatible with each other, i think that's the problem with you.

Please find below compatibilities:

```
DJ 5.x works with JasperReposrts 4.6+ (and 5.0+, 5.1+ and 5.2) and needs JDK 1.6
DJ 4.x workrs with JasperReports 4.1 to 4.5.x
DJ 3.0.5 works with JR 3.5 up to 4.0
```

Note: Make sure Your `jrxml` is compiled with `Jasper` version.